# Node.js/javascript helper for default value using typeof operator

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm getting tired to have to always write this kind of code:

```
<% box_content = typeof box_content != 'undefined' ? box_content : ''%>
<% box_class = typeof box_class != 'undefined' ? box_class : 'box'%>
```

Does node.js or javascript (or a node module) have any helper for this?
A simple function that return a default value or `false` if the default value isn't provided.

We need this so often, I don't understand why there is nothing in the node.js framework to help developpers to deal with that.

I'm thinking about adding this to my project but I would rather prefer having this in `underscore.js` as utility function for instance. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, in this example, but I need it not only in EJS.

Comment: In EJS the right way would be to use an object, as in `locals` and just check for keys in that object instead of checking if multiple variables are defined.

Comment: I guess it's really hard to write your own one line function? `function default(x, val) { return typeof x==='undefined' ? val : x; }` ?

Comment: Also, note that you can compare against undefined directly if the variable has been declared: `box_content !== undefined`. Saves a few keystrokes.

Comment: @torazaburo No it is not hard, that's not the *point*. The point is that this *should* belong to node.js framework by default. And if not then to a library to use it the same across client and browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided that `box_content` and `box_class` are *declared*, but their values may be undefined, then you can use `||` — [JavaScript's curiously-powerful OR operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html):

```
<% box_content = box_content || ''%>
<% box_class = box_class || 'box'%>
```

Unlike the logical OR operator in most languages, JavaScript's `||` returns the left-hand operand if its value is "truthy" or it's right-hand operand if it isn't. Any value that isn't "falsey" is truthy; the "falsey" values are `0`, `""`, `NaN`, `undefined`, `null`, or (of course) `false`.

It's important to remember **not** to use this when a falsey value is valid; that can be a "gotcha." But quite frequently falsey values are not relevant, and so this is a very handy way to default things.

---

It seems from comments below that you don't care for the curiously-powerful `||` operator.

The answer, then, is no — but you can trivially create your own:

```
function foo(val, defVal) {
    return typeof val === "undefined" ? defVal : val;
}

<% box_content = foo(box_content, '')%>
<% box_class = foo(box_class, 'box')%>
```

Note that I didn't try to give `foo` a semantic name. Those are so subjective, you'll want your own anyway. :-)

Also note that this, too, requires that the variable be *declared* even if its value is `undefined`. If the variable may or may not be *declared*, the inline `typeof` is your only real option.

For **global** variables (only), this works whether the variables are declared or not:

```
function foo(varName, defValue) {
    var val;
    if (varName in global) {
        val = global[varName];
    }
    if (typeof val === "undefined") {
        val = defValue;
    }
    return val;
}
```

...where `global` is [NodeJS's global variable](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global) that refers to the global object (like `window` on browsers).

Usage *(note that the names of the variables are now strings)*:

```
<% box_content = foo('box_content', '')%>
<% box_class = foo('box_class', 'box')%>
```

But again, it's only useful for globals, which presumably you're avoiding using.

Comment: This wouldn't work if box_content is set as `false` boolean value.

Comment: @Vadorequest: Indeed not. Which seems unlikely if the alternative is `'box'`.

Comment: The thing is to having one way to deal with default values, not having to always think about what should contain the variable. This is not good enough because there are exceptions with falsy values.

Comment: @Vadorequest: I agree you have to be aware of what you're doing. That's kind of a general rule. And yet, `||` is ***very*** frequently good enough. It's good enough for strings when `""` isn't a valid value, numbers where `0` and `NaN` aren't valid values, object references when `null` isn't a valid value, ...

Comment: There is no magic bullet, you have to check for whatever you're expecting. As mentioned  above, for EJS or other frameworks where you pass values and they are magically instanciated as variables, you pass an object so you only have to check for one single variable being defined, after that you check for keys in the object, which is much simpler.

Answer (score -1):

This is probably hacky, but here's a way to have a function that will let you input a nonexistant var without error;

```
function foo(inputVar,backupPlanVar){
   with(arguments.callee.caller){
      var evalVar;
      try{
         evalVar = this[inputVar];
      }catch(e){
         evalVar = backupPlanVar || undefined;
      }
      return evalVar;
   }
}

var abc = 123
foo('abc');
> 123
foo('nonExistantVariable');
> undefined
foo('nonExists', 456);
> 456
```

I would hesitate to actually use this, but maybe in some templating code?

Comment: That will only work for global variables (for which there's a dramatically better solution). There's no purpose to using `with (arguments.callee.caller)`; it doesn't, for instance, let you access variables in the calling context. And of course, `caller` is disallowed in strict mode.

Comment: I admit this was not ideal, but I thought it might inspire the OP to devise a solution. But good job down voting my answer, editing your post to include an idea from it, and then post a snide comment about how bad it was - But of course, let's not forget or forgive that `caller` is disallowed in strict mode.